# Compatibility restrictions of different versions of the mysql2 gem w/ mysql servers?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mariadb, mysql2

i am in a situation where i have to upgrade my underlying mysql database from Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73 to a newer and more up-to-date version (I can select), or even migrate to mariadb.  My app has been running an older version of the mysql2 gem (0.3.21), and I would like to know if there are known compatibility issues with connecting to newer mysql instances.  I'd had problems...

When using a remote MariaDB instance, my app reports "Lost Connection" error.  Using the local 5.1.73 client to the mariadb server, I get 'The server has gone away'.

When using an upgraded MySQL instance (5.7), the app reports "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110".  This seems to be a handshake issue.

I've been able to successfully connect from a random IP address using an sql client application so I know these are not firewall issues.  The databases are managed, and firewall has been turned off.

Any suggestions?  I am trying to keep this app as stable as possible without having to upgrade it.

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of the gem. `mysql2` hasn't made a lot of breaking changes so it's probably fine, but if not, kick it ahead at least a little. Try `0.4.10` if not the current one. Don't forget "stable" may mean "full of severe vulnerabilities", so be sure to check you're not exposed.

Comment: Upgrading the gem requires multiple updates of other gem dependencies which ultimately lead to an update of ruby (which i have to avoid).

Comment: If you've let this one go a little too long then it's time to pay down that debt. The longer you let it go, the more expensive the update will be. I know it's annoying and frustrating, but the alternative is to let even more problems pile up, making this exponentially more difficult to resolve.